# How do I customize a JComboBox so that the pop-up is a JTree (instead of a list)?

Tags: java, swing, popup, jtree, jcombobox

I am trying to create a combo box so that I can put whatever control I prefer within the pop-up, in my specific case a JTree. Having a look at how the JComboBox is implement, the pop-up is really created by the UI delegate. The problem in changing that is that it would need to be re-implemented for each look and feel, which is something I do not want to do...

I basically want a component that it has the look and feel of a JComboBox (in the current look and feel) and the popup is a JTree (in the current look and feel).

What's the easiest way to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the concept. When the tree pops up will you be able to select a node from the tree and have that value display in the combo box? When the tree pops up is the node in the tree already selected/expanded based on the value in the combo box? Or is this simply a way to display a tree on a mouse click?

Comment: The first case: tree pops up, node already selected (if any), click on a node, the JComboBox fires an ActionEvent to signal that the selection changed and the tree disappear. I actually have a way to display a tree on a mouse click (using a JCommandButton in the flamingo component suite).

Answer (score 2):

JComboBox itself can't do what you want. If you're absolutely wedded to the concept of having it act like a JComboBox, you could make a JButton pop up a JPanel on click. Then the JPanel could have whatever you want inside it (JTree, etcetera).

Comment: Yeah, that's how I am doing it right now. The problem is that I want to embed this in a JTable as a TableCellEditor, and having a button in there is quite ugly... :-/

Answer (score 1):

I've had a go at producing something that would do something like this.

At first, I tried to implement something along the lines suggested by Varun, but it was proving to be a bit messy, and I get a little nervous when I start playing with ComponentUI objects (I'd rather leave that sort of thing to the L&F). If anyone has a good example of doing this, I'd be interested to see it.

So then I tried the button approach... and thought I would share the code with the SO community:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalComboBoxIcon;

public class MockJComboBox extends JPanel  {

  private boolean _isPoppedUp = false;

  public MockJComboBox(String label, final JComponent toShow) {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JLabel jLabel = new JLabel(label);
    jLabel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    add(jLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    Icon icon = new MetalComboBoxIcon();

    final JInternalFrame popup = new JInternalFrame(null, false, false, false, false);
    final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    panel.add(new JScrollPane(toShow), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    if(!(System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Mac OS"))){
      BasicInternalFrameUI ui = (BasicInternalFrameUI) popup.getUI();
      ui.getNorthPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0,0));
    }
    popup.setBorder(null);
    popup.setContentPane(panel);
    popup.pack();
    popup.setVisible(true);

    final JButton dropDownButton = new JButton(icon);
    dropDownButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        _isPoppedUp = !_isPoppedUp;
        Container parent = getParent();
        if (_isPoppedUp) {
          popup.setLocation(panel.getX(), panel.getY() + panel.getHeight());
          popup.setSize(panel.getWidth(), toShow.getHeight());
          parent.add(popup);
        } else {
          parent.remove(popup);
          parent.repaint();
        }
      }
    });
    add(dropDownButton, BorderLayout.EAST);
  }

  public boolean isPoppedUp() {
    return _isPoppedUp;
  }
}
```

If you spot any bugs or have suggestions on how to improve this code, I'd be grateful for your comments!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to extend the BasicComboBoxUI and then override required methods like

```
public static ComponentUI createUI( JComponent c)
```

and

```
protected ComboPopup createPopup()
```

Creating a custom ComboPopup would require you to put some effort where you can't use the BasicComboPopUp because it extends JPopUpMenu

```
public class BasicComboPopup extends JPopupMenu implements ComboPopup
```

So in your case you may want to extend JTree and implement ComboPopup.

I'm doubt about "The problem in changing that is that it would need to be re-implemented for each look and feel" part. I don't think that there will be a problem of re-implementation.

The BasicComboPopup looks differently in different look and feels because it is a JPopupMenu which in turn will have UI delegates. So if you simply extend a JTree you should not be having problems with different look and feels.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to use a button that pops up a JPanel with a JTree is correct.  In response to Carcassi's comment, you can use a custom TableCellRenderer to change it so that it does not look like the traditional button.

Answer (score 0):

Further web research revealed that [Jidesoft](http://www.jidesoft.com/), who describe themselves as "a professional Java and Swing component provider" produce a package called [JIDE Grids](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/grids.htm), which includes [AbstractComboBox](http://www.jidesoft.com/javadoc/com/jidesoft/combobox/AbstractComboBox.html) - the description for which suggests it would do this.

However, it's a paid-for package and I haven't tried it... If anyone has used this, could they comment on the experience?